# Get raw pixel of jpg with imagemagick

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, pixel, grayscale

I want to get raw pixel of jpg image that have 2,2kib of size. So I used this command

```
convert image.jpg -depth 16 image.gray
```

so the size of image.gray is 1,7kib, but why? Raw pixel must be greater than jpg because jpe is compressed image or Am I wrong?

Comment: The jpg may carry meta data of considerable size such as profiles and clip paths. The raw gray image has no meta data.  How did you measure the file sizes? Perhaps if you post a link to your JPG file, we can see what is going on. Also what is your version of ImageMagick and your platform?

Comment: ImageMaagick is 6.7.8-1 version and I am using arduino Yun with openWRT. I measure the file size using folder on web gui interface of arduino yun

Comment: This link is my jpg image https://ibb.co/jpw0D8

Comment: But if jpg is biiger than raw pixel data so why jpg is a compress format? So I feel that I am in bad direction

Comment: If I do: `convert imagen_Sensor0012441.jpg GRAY:test.gray` in ImageMagick 6.9.9.46. Then use the Mac file system to get the file sizes: your jpg is 2,049 bytes and the gray image is 19,200 bytes. So the gray image is much larger than the jpg. How did you get the file sizes you report?

Comment: I tried with convert imagen_Sensor0012441.jpg GRAY:test.gray but it give me error that it is not recognized GRAY

Comment: This may be Image Magick v 6.7.8-1 issue. I got proper results on Windows with 7.0.6-10 and your command: image.gray with size of 38400 bytes. Please try to either upgrade the version or add `-size` parameter. If this doesnt help inspect your image.gray.

Comment: Using ImageMagick 6.7.8.9 and `convert imagen_Sensor0012441.jpg GRAY:test.gray`, I still get 19,200 bytes compared to the original jpg at 2,048 bytes. Your version 6.7.8.1 is about 250 versions old. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Can you test Magick v 6.7.8-1, meanwhile I test other version? because openwrt only have Magick v 6.7.8-1, and I download other version and compile

Comment: I do not work I have a problem with gray parametters